# mysql SELECT 0 or 1 when LIKE is found

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to return a 0/1 when a LIKE is found.
I had it working with a CASE IF statement on a different query which uses a MATCH AGAINST. But I can't seem to get this working.
for example: this worked in the SELECT part of the query.

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN IF((MATCH (name) AGAINST ("rubert"  IN BOOLEAN MODE))>=1, 1, 0) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as r2....
```

But i'm looking for a 0 or a 1 against a LIKE.

eq.

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN IF (name LIKE "%rubert%") == FOUND) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as found FROM....
```

Have a feeling i'm really close, but seem not to get it exactly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it.

```
SELECT name LIKE '%rubert%' FROM...
```

In MySQL, all booleans are represented as `1` or `0`, and `LIKE` returns a boolean. No work needed.

The reason your `MATCH` query needs an `IF` is the fact that `MATCH` returns a float, not a boolean; otherwise, this would be enough:

```
SELECT MATCH name AGAINST ('rubert' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM...
```

To whittle it down though, you're going through both `IF` and `CASE`, which is totally too much, as this is enough:

```
SELECT IF(MATCH name AGAINST ('rubert' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 1, 1, 0) AS goodenough FROM...
```

Comment: @Fireblade: I don't use Windows except for gaming, so no idea about MS SQL. But for example with Oracle, it's been 10 years since I worked with it, and it wouldn't have worked with it then (since it did not have booleans as a data type despite having operators that return booleans, and is not smart enough to convert to a data type that it actually can use. Or rather, its syntax is limited so that boolean stuff can only happen as an operand to stuff that needs conditions. I hated Oracle.) No idea about now, I stick to MySQL and SQLite3.

Comment: I need to comment on the last thing you said about going through the IF and CASE. This was due to it being part of a larger query in which I needed a CASE. In case other people read this thread. Tnx

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap it by function

```
USE `test`;
DROP function IF EXISTS `is_exists`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`is_exists` (q varchar(50))
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
DECLARE is_exist INT(11);
DECLARE que varchar(50);
SELECT CONCAT("%",q,"%") INTO que; 
SELECT count(*) into is_exist FROM `test`.`users` WHERE `fname` LIKE que;
IF is_exist >0 THEN 
RETURN 1;
ELSE
RETURN 0;
END IF;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And than

```
SELECT is_user_exists("your query");
```

Good luck!

Comment: sorry,but this is not related. The above answer is correct

Comment: @renevdkooi You can make the changes as your need. Anyway, Good luck